# Django, convert data from JSON to DB

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I want to implement this Vue.js component, but I want data from JSON in this case: tasks( todo with description) will be saved at my Database.

I try find a best solution.
User create a new "todo" and then Django save it to DB.

```
{
  "newTodoText": "",
  "todos": {
    "regular": [
      "Do the dishes",
      "Take out the trash",
      "Mow the lawn"
    ],
    "priority": [],
    "done": []
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/supraniti/full/zogjGW

What would be the best way to do this in Python? Can you give me idea, solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json is basically a dict and in your models, you can modify the save function and map the dict keys to the corresponding model field. here's some [documentation reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/)

in models.py, you would need a Task(or Todo) model

```
class Task(models.Model):
""" unit of work to be done"""

PRIORITY_LOW = 1
PRIORITY_MEDIUM = 2
PRIORITY_HIGH = 3
PRIORITY_CRITICAL = 4

PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
    (PRIORITY_LOW, 'low'),
    (PRIORITY_MEDIUM, 'medium'),
    (PRIORITY_HIGH, 'high'),
    (PRIORITY_CRITICAL, 'critical'),
)

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
priority = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,
                                  default=PRIORITY_MEDIUM)
is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```